# Asking about mysql command select from tabel?

Tags: mysql

I need mysql command to show all tabel with out number id 5 like this

Select * from table ( Except 5 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from table
Where id <> 5
```

I suggest you read more on : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/